# VBA - How to use multiple criteria from a range with wildcards, for autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I need to filter some values of a sheet, and these values that I need to filter is in a table, but this one is dynamic, sometimes there's only one value, or two,three... Ex: Today i'll be ' ABC - CBA - DDA ' , and tomorrow ' DNC - AB '. Here is my code of filters that I also need to use with this:

```
        totrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 9)).AutoFilter
        Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(totrow, 6)).Select
        
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(totrow, 6)).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="816"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(totrow, 2)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="RWK"
        
        '**here goes the other filters**
```

Comment: Not sure what your question or actual problem is.

Comment: BigBen I actually need to filter some values, and these values is in a dynamic table, so I can't know what values it is

Comment: Ok. Where is that table? How are you trying to dynamically read its values?

Comment: That's the question. I need to filter everything that is different with its values

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you have the criteria's in a dynamic table. Sometimes the table is expanding so you want to catch those values (the filter values might be changing too). These values are then used to filter another range.

Comment: Wizhi, that's it! I just put the values in an array, so now I 'm looking for how to filter values that is in an array..

Comment: As I don't know where you have your table with the values to filter, I have made a general example. For me the "table" is in column N.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have set of data that we want to filter:

[image]

and we also have a column/range with values we want to use as filter (Column N).

If the values always are the same, we can use in our filtering a hard coded array:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array("ABC - CBA - DDA", "DNC - AB")
```

However, if the values or range are changing, we need to create a dynamic array that loops through our range and store the values as an array.

```
'Create an array to store the values to filter on
ReDim aCritVal(0 To lrow_crit) As Variant 'Create an array variable "aCritVal" to store the Criteria Value we want to use as filter
i = 0 'Array index starts at 0
For Each CellVal In ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, "N"), ws.Cells(lrow_crit, "N")) 'Range to loop through where Criteria Values exists
    'Debug.Print CellVal.Value 'Checks the cell value that will be stored in Array: aCritVal
    aCritVal(i) = CellVal.Value 'Store the value in array
    i = i + 1 'Add one to next loop
Next CellVal
ReDim Preserve aCritVal(i - 1) 'Resize the array to only contain the values we need
```

Then we can substitute the array from:

`Criteria1:=Array("ABC - CBA - DDA", "DNC - AB")` -> `Criteria1:=aCritVal`

We can also add additional filtering steps to our filter section.

With the code below, where we use 3 filtering (1 array + 2 additional criteria's) we will get:
[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub auto_filter_from_critera_range()

Dim lrow_filter As Long
Dim lcol_filter As Long
Dim lrow_crit As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim CellVal As Variant
Dim MyRangeFilter As Range


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the worksheet name

lrow_crit = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in criteria table, in Sheet1
lrow_filter = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row for filter, in Sheet1
lcol_filter = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find last column for filter, Sheet1


'Create an array to store the values to filter on
ReDim aCritVal(0 To lrow_crit) As Variant 'Create an array variable "aCritVal" to store the Criteria Value we want to use as filter
i = 0 'Array index starts at 1
For Each CellVal In ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, "N"), ws.Cells(lrow_crit, "N")) 'Range to loop through where Criteria Values exists
    'Debug.Print CellVal.Value 'Checks the cell value that will be stored in Array: aCritVal
    aCritVal(i) = CellVal.Value 'Store the value in array
    i = i + 1 'Add one to next loop
Next CellVal
ReDim Preserve aCritVal(i - 1) 'Resize the array to only contain the values we need


If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False 'If autofilter exists then remove autofilter
Set MyRangeFilter = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lrow_filter, lcol_filter)) 'Define the range to apply autofilter
' MyRangeFilter.Select 'Select the range to filter, might be needed in some instances
                
With MyRangeFilter
    '.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array("ABC - CBA - DDA", "DNC - AB"), Operator:=xlFilterValues '"Normal" array that can be used if we have fixed criteria values
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=aCritVal, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Our array value that we crated in the above section, that will be used as filter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="816" '"Regular" critera value
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="RWK"
End With

End Sub
```

---

The criteria range should only include the values for the criteria we want to filter. *Please notice* that I have used header for the filter criteria at row 2, as I use `lcol_filter` to find the last column to apply filter, therefore I put the filter table on row 2 and the first value will be in row 3.

```
For Each CellVal In ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, "N"), ws.Cells(lrow_crit, "N"))
    '.......
Next CellVal
```

---

For wildcard in the array:

```
Criteria1:=Array("*CBA*", "*AB*")
```

Change the part of the code where we store the values and add asterix:
`aCritVal(i) = CellVal.Value` -> `aCritVal(i) = "*" & CellVal.Value & "*"`

Comment: Yeah!! It works well! Now the only thing I need to do is to formate the filter, something like   .AutoFilter Field:= 8, Criteria1:= (* aCritVal *), Operator:= xlFilterValues   ... Kind of filter the array values, but I don't care what comes before it or next...

Comment: I think this should work. Change this `aCritVal(i) = CellVal.Value` -> `aCritVal(i) = "*" & CellVal.Value & "*"`